# Java Web Service background process to update service data

Tags: java, web-services, background-process

I have a simple Tomcat 7 Server where I want to implement a Java Web Service which offers some data I can get via my mobile phone.
The point is I want the data on the server being updated every once in a while. So I need a "background process" which updates the data.

I first tried to start a new thread in the constructor of my binding implementation class (which implements only my own Service - not a HttpServlet or so) like

```
public NewBindingImpl(){   
  Thread informationFetcher = new InformationFetcher();   
  informationFetcher.start(); 
}
```

But I didn't think about the fact that this class gets created every time someone is using the service. Further more this would update the data only the moment I ask for them. But how could I update them lets say every two hours or so?

Hopefully someone here has an idea. Is that even possible for a "simple" web service?

Thank you very much,

Tobias

**EDIT: ----**

Maybe it helps to know that I tried this very basic tutorial here:

http://www.elearning.witnut.com/230/java-web-service-creation-using-top-development-approach/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not initialise the thread when the servlet's `init()` method is called ? You can shut it down when the corresponding `destroy()` method is called. The thread will be bound to the lifecycle of the servlet and since `init()` is only called once, you won't have to worry about multiple instances.

Here's a brief tutorial on the [init() method usage](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/bestpractices/using_httpservlet_method.html).

Since you want something running every two hours, check out the [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class. For more complex scenarios [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) is a serious contender.

Comment: Sounds ok so far but could you give me a hint how to do that? Unfortunately it's the first time I'm working with a Tomcat server.

Comment: It's a servlet facility rather than specific to Tomcat. See the tutorial linked above

Comment: Thank you. I will read this first and hope things aren't that different from an "ordinary" servlet to a web service. :-)

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get this. 
I thought I have to write this in my bindingImplementation class which only implements my service Interface. So this class is no Servlet. Where should I do what they do in the tutorial with the HttpServlet? 
Am I thinking in the wrong direction?

Comment: Well, it was not exactly what I was looking for but I guess my question was not concrete enough. So thanks for the moment. If I face further problems I'll ask again! :-)